# Java linking int value to a random generated code

Tags: java, random, time

I'm trying to build simple java net cafe timer. I done random code generator. Now i need to be able to add custom time amount to every code or to generate multiple codes with same amount of time i.e. 30 codes with 30 min time. Code is created as hexadecimal values.
SO it should be something like this

```
1EEE has 30 minutes
CDB9 has 60 minutes
and so on
```

Latter i will implement client/server, and user will be able to use computer for the time he/she has on time code.

Code for generating time codes:

```
public String createRandomTimeCode(int length) {
        Random random = new Random();
        StringBuilder code = new StringBuilder();
        while (code.length() < length) {
            code.append(Integer.toHexString(random.nextInt()));
        }

        String Short = code.substring(0,4);

        return Short.toString();
```

I wasn't clear. My question was how to store different values like time codes + amount of time on that code. And i got the answer in comments.

Comment: What is the question? Are looking for Map (HashMap for example)?

Comment: I'm bit confused about what exactly you are asking for. As the kutchkem asked.. is a `Map`  you're looking fo?

Comment: Hi, You can use following code.  

public class RandomCodeGenarator {
    public int getRandomCode() {
        return new Random().nextInt(1000000) + 0;
    }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your looking for is `HashMap`